# Ping specific route through network back to same computer on different interface

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, routes, ping

I have a topology setup in GNS3 running a number of virtual machines (pictured below.)  R1, R2, and R3 are routers (built in Ubuntu) that I am running tests on.  'Test' is another Ubuntu virtual machine that is controlling my tests.

I would like to be able to ping from the interface on 'Test' with address 10.0.4.3, through R2, then through R1, then back to 'Test' at the interface with IP 10.0.5.2

Ideally I would like to be able to treat each network interface on 'Test' as a separate logical computer, so I could simply say ping 10.0.5.2 from 10.0.4.3 and let the routing protocols forward the message through the route of their choosing.

The tests are automated, so splitting 'Test' into four separate virtual machines would be less than ideal.

Any ideas?

[image: my topology]

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this particular scenario, i think the solution for what you want would be to virtualize machines over the "test" machine, with this approach each machine would be in a different subnet. BUT, i'm not sure how better it would be when comparing to multiple "test" machines...

Another option, since it's a simple scenario and you only showed interest in testing routing protocols is to build this scenario in a simulator called Packet Tracer, by Cisco. In this scenario, you would still need more "test" machines but you wouldn't have to worry about you computer processor. The downside is that you'd need to use Cisco devices instead of Linux Machines to configure your routing topology.

Arthur Passos.